# В случае удаления view элемента методом setVisibility(View.GONE) как запустить сначала анимацию

Tags: android, анимация

Имеется метод onTouch, в котором указано, что при касании на view1 под ним появляется view2, а при следующем касании по view1 view2 скрывается.

В коде удаление view2 прописано так: `view2.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Однако есть еще и анимация ухода view2:

```
view2.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this,true));
```

которая прописана строчкой выше (перед удалением).

По факту все срабатывает так:

1. view2 удаляется
2. анимация показывает, как view2 уезжает вправо.

Т.е., когда view2 уже нет, анимация все еще показывает, как view2 уезжает вправо.

Дело в том, что при удалении view2, его место занимает другой view, поэтому все выглядит не очень красиво.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы было так:

1. анимация показывает, как view2 уезжает вправо
2. view2 удаляется

Comment: Пробовали просто местами поменять? или просто убрать GONE и только анимацию оставить?

Comment: нет, не пробовала, но вот сейчас ради эксперимента попробовала. Если убрать GONE, то view2 не исчезает и анимации соответственно нет, если просто местами переставить ничего не меняется

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Отследите окончание анимации, где измените видимость.

```
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this, true);

        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```